# How to properly build a "criterion-like" filter over a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

How do I build a Criterion-like (like we have on Hibernate (Java)) filtering for PHP arrays?

**little explanation**

Here I built a basic "Criterion" object to dynamically add conditions to a SQL string statement just like this (`select *` is just a sample, for the sake of simplicity):

```
public function GetAll($where_hashmap = null, Closure $optionalFn = null)
{
    // function that retrieve table name from concrete class implementation
    $table = $this->getTableName();

    $sql = "select * from {$table}";
    $params = array();
    if ($where_hashmap != null)
    {
        $sql .= " where 1=1";
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($where_hashmap); $i++)
        {
            $column = $where_hashmap[$i]["column"];
            $logic = $where_hashmap[$i]["logic"]; // AND, OR, NOT, ...
            $comparator = $where_hashmap[$i]["comparator"]; // <, <=, >, >=, =, !=, IN ...
            $value = $where_hashmap[$i]["value"];
            $sql .= " {$logic} {$column} {$comparator} ? "; // i.e. AND column <= ?
            array_push($params, $value);
        }
    }
    // function that take the SQL statement, parameters and an optional function, 
    // prepare and execute the statement
    return $this->Query($sql, $params, $optionalFn); 
}
```

This is kinda simple, because we are dynamically adding conditions to a SQL string. But now, I need to do this to an in-memory array. The `array_filter()` function from PHP do this pretty well when "we program by ourselves" the callback (criteria) function (like the sample below, from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php))

```
array_filter($arr, function($v, $k) {
    return $k == 'b' || $v == 4; // all our criteria from $where_hashmap should be here
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

How could I dinamically build the `if` statement, without hard-coding all possible cases for the logical and relational operations? Should I write a function in a PHP file at runtime? Is this approach scallable?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Dynamically building an anonymous function at run-time is perfectly valid; but you might want to consider one of the PHP implementations of LINQ

Comment: I'll think about this, @MarkBaker. Thank you anyway.